# Changing opacity of one button changes all of them

Tags: java, android, xml

I've run into this problem in the past, and the way I fixed it last time was just creating a new .png file for every button (even though they are the same). However, I'm looking for more of a professional, efficient solution.

Basically, I have 7 buttons in my app. All of them use background.png as their background. Part of my code tells the app to 'lock' certain buttons until they are unlocked. However, when I go to set the alpha of one button, they are all affected. Is there an easier solution other than creating 6 duplicates of background.png and renaming them?

My code is pretty standard:

**Within my XML layout file:**

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BUTTON TEXT"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"/>
```

**My custom buttom XML file that is referenced for my buttons:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_unpressed" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_depressed" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_unpressed" />
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_unpressed" />
</selector>
```

**Lastly the code I'm using to alter my buttons:**

```
button.setEnabled(false);
button.setText("BUTTON TEXT");
button.getBackground().setAlpha(122);
```

Comment: Do not change the alpha of the background. Change the alpha of the view (button).

Comment: button.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(122);

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`button.getBackground().setAlpha(122);`

with

`button.setAlpha(122);`

Comment: I've tried this as well, and to no avail. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops: Inside my custom button XML all I had to do was create a new .png of the button disabled (a bit darker). After this I removed the code to change the alpha value completely, and now all is good! When I disable the button programatically, the color changes to the .png file specified in my XML file.

Answer (score 0):

assign background in codefor every button:

```
 Drawable drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button);
    b5.setBackground(drawable);
    drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button);
    b6.setBackground(drawable);
```